# FILTER formula throws error when combining with SUBSTITUTE Google Formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, match, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to generalize the FILTER formula

I have, which gives me what I need

`=FILTER(iConnectionsHelper!A1:L, iConnectionsHelper!K1:K<>"", iConnectionsHelper!L1:L<>"")`
 But the last column letter `L` keeps changing, which then, in turn, changes the column letters `K and L`

So I have, get the last column header column with data

`=left(address(1,counta(iConnectionsHelper!$A1:$AA1),2),find("$",address(1,counta(iConnectionsHelper!$A1:$AA1),2))-1)`

Get the Column letter from the Header name:

`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("From Name",'iConnectionsHelper'!A1:AA1,0),4),1,"")` = K

`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("To Name",'iConnectionsHelper'!A1:AA1,0),4),1,"")` = L

But if I try to use these in the Filter formula

```
 =FILTER("iConnectionsHelper!A1:"&left(address(1,counta(iConnectionsHelper!$A1:$AA1),2),find("$",address(1,counta(iConnectionsHelper!$A1:$AA1),2))-1), "iConnectionsHelper!K1:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("matchFrom",iConnectionsHelper!A1:AA1,0),4),1,"")<>"", "iConnectionsHelper!L1:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("matchTo",iConnectionsHelper!A1:AA1,0),4),1,"")<>"")
```

The output is `iConnectionsHelper!A1:L`

How to get this to work?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each time you construct the range you need to use `INDIRECT`. try:

```
=FILTER(INDIRECT("iConnectionsHelper!A1:"&LEFT(
 ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(iConnectionsHelper!$A1:$AA1), 2), FIND("$", 
 ADDRESS(1, COUNTA(iConnectionsHelper!$A1:$AA1), 2))-1)),
 INDIRECT("iConnectionsHelper!K1:"&SUBSTITUTE(
 ADDRESS(1, MATCH("matchFrom", iConnectionsHelper!A1:AA1, 0), 4), 1, ))<>"", 
 INDIRECT("iConnectionsHelper!L1:"&SUBSTITUTE(
 ADDRESS(1, MATCH("matchTo", iConnectionsHelper!A1:AA1, 0), 4), 1, ))<>"")
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that!